# UserControl с эффектом выделения и контекстное меню

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, usercontrol

Имеется UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShikiDesk.Controls.ShortInfoControl"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShikiDesk.Controls"
                 mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Source="{Binding Poster.original}" 
                   Width="150" Height="200"
                   StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RusName}" Margin="0,5" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Medium" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Text="{Binding Description}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

В окно он подключается следующим образом:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" BorderThickness="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">
                    <controls:ShortInfoControl Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Выглядит это всё примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос в следующем:**

Можно ли при наведении добавить эффект выделения, подобно тому, что есть в ListView?
Можно ли добавить контекстное меню? Причём такое, чтобы при нажатии на ПКМ было понятно в каком из блоков было вызвано контекстное меню.

Comment: Используйте ListBox вместо ItemsControl, если хотите иметь выделение.

Comment: @Gardes, а как мне с ListView добиться такого же формата отображения?

Comment: @Mr.Modest: А как отображается сейчас с ListView?

Comment: @VladD в вопросе же указано.. формат списка блоков описан в UserControl, который задаётся как шаблон для ItemControl

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Можно влиять на отображение, используя `ItemTemplate` и `ItemsContainer`

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Я имею в виду, если заменить на ListView, как будет выглядеть?

Comment: @VladD не знаю, не пробовал же ещё) я полагал, что ListView будет лишь узкие строки отображать, поэтому сразу перешёл к такому варианту

Comment: @VladD получилось вот такое: http://pastexen.com/i/Qrrski4zL4.png  как теперь запретить ему уходить в горизонтальный скролл? ListView лежит в Grid в столбце с Width="*", чтобы он занимал всё оставшееся пространство.. не хочу давать ему фиксированную ширину

Comment: @Mr.Modest: `<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...`?

Comment: @VladD помогло спасибо. а что на счёт контекстного меню? как его сделать для каждого пункта списка?

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Ну, определите его в `UserControl`'е, по идее. Должно работать.

Comment: @VladD спасибо..

Comment: @Mr.Modest: Тогда оформлю в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего не пытаться добавить выделение к `ItemsControl` (это не так просто), а настроить вид `ListView`.

Чтобы запретить горизонтальный скроллинг, нужно дописать

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
```

А контекстное меню стоит сделать частью `UserControl`'а.